Why is there a discrepancy between storage usage in Exchange Admin Center and 'Get-MailboxFolderStatistics'?
I'm currently working on Exchange license storage usage analysis and encountered a discrepancy between the storage usage size shown in the Exchange Admin Center (EAC) for each user and the size reported by the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet.
Exchange Admin center storage image
PowerShell cmdlets storage image
Specifically, I used the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity  | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -eq "/Top of Information Store"} | Select-Object Name,FolderAndSubFolderSize | Format-List cmdlet to retrieve the size of the "Top of Information Store" folder and its subfolders.
However, the storage size displayed in the EAC differs from the FolderAndSubFolderSize reported by the cmdlet.
What could be causing this difference in reported storage usage between the Exchange Admin Center and the size retrieved from the "Top of Information Store" folder using Get-MailboxFolderStatistics? Are there specific factors or data that the Admin Center includes/excludes compared to this PowerShell cmdlet?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

"The Mailbox usage report does not include Recoverable Items as they are included in the Recoverable Items mailbox quota."
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/mailbox-usage?view=o365-worldwide
That should be the difference, get-mailboxstatistics would give the size including RecoverableItems folder, which helps the users recover deleted e-mails.

Thank you for your answer. I’m seeing that the size reported by Get-MailboxFolderStatistics for the Top of Information Store is smaller than the size shown in the Exchange Admin Center (EAC).
I understand the Recoverable Items folder has its own quota and isn’t included in the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics size. However, the EAC still shows a larger size than the cmdlet.
Could there be other hidden data or metadata that the EAC includes but the cmdlet doesn’t? I’d appreciate any insights on what might be causing this difference. Thanks!

Please use get-mailboxfolder Ref: f https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolder?view=exchange-ps to list the folders and get-mailboxfolderstatistics for each of the folders (probably w/ one-liner script). OR you may add "-FolderScope All" to your existing query if you did not specify  in get-mailboxfolderstatistics command to list all the types of folders for cross check. These commands may fill the gap and reveal the missing parts.

Thank you for the suggestion! I’ve already tried using Get-MailboxFolder and Get-MailboxFolderStatistics with the -FolderScope All option to include hidden and system folders. I also cross-checked the sizes, but the cmdlet still reports a smaller size than the EAC. Could there be additional metadata or system data the EAC accounts for that isn’t captured by these cmdlets? Any further insights would be appreciated!

Mobile activesync devices may have specific folders like VIP folder.
